# Hotkey for "Kde button" menu? And default shortcut-keys cheatsheets?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, default, documentation

What's the hotkey to open that thing in KDE that's basically like the Windows' "Start" menu?

I've found it surprisingly hard to find some basic hotkey cheatsheets for my shiny new install of Kubuntu... Anybody know of any?

Comment: Despite [overwhelming popular support since 2009, opening the launcher with Super/Win still not implemented in KDE](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=39073)!

Comment: Yeah, I've since moved on to gentoo with the "awesome" window manager (cuz my boyfriend set me up with a copy of his gentoo install and awesome is what he's using right now. it's not that great actually, and we're thinking about experimenting with stumpwm instead when we get the time, but at least awesome frees you to implement something that actually does what you want, and without lagging, if you can code it). honestly, kde and kubuntu in particular seem to be kinda rotting, and you especially notice the performance problems on top of the bad design when you're stuck on old hardware like me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no hotkey by default, you can configure a hotkey though. Right-click the KDE launcher button and select "Application Launcher Settings". Then go the Keyboard Shortcut tab.

> I've found it surprisingly hard to find some basic hotkey cheatsheets for my shiny new install of Kubuntu... Anybody know of any?

In any application, you can go to Settings→Configure Shortcuts to view the shortcuts. To view global shortcuts, you can open the "Global Shortcuts" configuration module from System Settings.

Answer (score 13):

Alt + F1 is the default combination to open the 'start menu'/application launcher.

Comment: I just used Alt+F1 on Kubuntu. It opens the launcher/start menu. Alt+F2 opens the command search/run box at the top. This is from Mint, but it's KDE...  http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/47

Comment: On a related note: for Xubuntu and Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS), FYI, use `ctrl + ESC` to open up the "Start" menu

Answer (score 3):

If you **just want to launch an application**, press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (just like on a mac).